# Rails 4: Undefined method `total_price' for nil:NilClass, Order Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble having order go through. I have posted the error bellow. I think the issue has to do with the create method in the OrderController.rb, I do have the total_price method already defined but.. other than that I'm not sure how to fix the issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

```
class OrderTransaction
  def initialize order, nonce
    @order = order
    @nonce = nonce
  end

  def execute
    @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
      amount: order.total_price,
      payment_method_nonce: nonce
    )
  end

  def ok?
    @result.success?
  end

  private

  attr_reader :order, :nonce
end
```

---

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_items

  def total_price
    order_items.inject(0) { |sum, item| sum + item.total_price }
  end
end
```

---

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :initialize_cart

  def index
    @orders = Order.order(created_at: :desc).all
  end

  def create
    @order_form = OrderForm.new(
      user: User.new(order_params[:user]),
      cart: @cart
    )

    if @order_form.save
      notify_user
      if charge_user
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thank you for placing the order."
      else
        flash[:warning] = <<EOF
Your order ID is #{@order_form.order.id}.
<br/>
Something went wrong.
EOF
        redirect_to new_payment_order_path(@order_form.order)
      end
    else
      render "carts/checkout"
    end
  end

  def update
    @order = Order.find params[:id]
    @previous_state = @order.state

    if @order.update state_order_params
      notify_user_about_state
      redirect_to orders_path, notice: "Order was updated."
    end
  end


  def new_payment
    @order = Order.find params[:id]
    @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate
  end

  def pay
    @order = Order.find params[:id]
    transaction = OrderTransaction.new @order, params[:payment_method_nonce]
    transaction.execute
    if transaction.ok?
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thank you for placing the order."
    else
      render "orders/new_payment"
    end
  end

  private

  def notify_user
    @order_form.user.send_reset_password_instructions
    OrderMailer.order_confirmation(@order_form.order).deliver
  end

  def notify_user_about_state
    OrderMailer.state_changed(@order, @previous_state).deliver
  end

  def order_params
    params.require(:order_form).permit(
      user: [ :name, :phone, :address, :city, :country, :postal_code, :email ]
    )
  end

  def charge_user
    transaction = OrderTransaction.new @order, params[:payment_method_nonce]
    transaction.execute
    transaction.ok?
  end

  def state_order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:state)
  end
end
```

---

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product

  def total_price
    self.quantity * self.product.price
  end
end
```

---

```
  class OrderForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :user, :order # credit_card
  attr_writer :cart

  def save
    set_password_for_user

    if valid?
      persist
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def has_errors?
    user.errors.any?
  end

  private

  def valid?
    user.valid?
  end

  def persist
    user.save
    @order = Order.create! user: user

    build_order_items
  end

  def set_password_for_user
    user.password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(user.email + Time.now.to_s)[0..8]
  end

  def build_order_items
    @cart.items.each do |item|
      @order.order_items.create! product_id: item.product_id, quantity: item.quantity
    end
  end

end
```

---

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product

  def total_price
    self.quantity * self.product.price
  end
end
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a standard note, any `NilClass` error basically means you haven't defined the variable you're trying to manipulate.

The key to solving the problem is to therefore find why the variable isn't defined, and populate it.

---

```
def execute
    @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
      amount: order.total_price,
      payment_method_nonce: nonce
    )
end
```

This is where Rails says the variable is not populated.

However, as with many problems in programming, the *cause* of the issue may not be as defined...

I initially thought the problem was that you weren't calling `@order`. However, the class initializes with `order`, so that shouldn't be a problem. So you have to look at how you're invoking the class:

```
transaction = OrderTransaction.new @order, params[:payment_method_nonce]
```

This surmises that `@order` is defined.

I surmise it isn't.

Here's what I'd do:

```
def create
    @order_form = OrderForm.new(
      user: User.new(order_params[:user]),
      cart: @cart
    )

    if @order_form.save
      notify_user
      @order = @order_form.order #-> not efficient but should create @order
      if charge_user
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thank you for placing the order."
      else
        flash[:warning] = <<EOF
Your order ID is #{@order_form.order.id}.
<br/>
Something went wrong.
EOF
        redirect_to new_payment_order_path(@order_form.order)
      end
    else
      render "carts/checkout"
    end
end
```

---

Personally, I think this highlights a deeper problem with your code structure:

> - You're creating an `OrderForm` object and yet processing `@order_form.order`
> - Your controller is full of tiny methods which bloat it up big time
> - Your controller is for *orders*, yet builds `OrderForm` objects

I'd do my best to make my [controller as thin as possible](http://www.slideshare.net/damiansromek/thin-controllers-fat-models-proper-code-structure-for-mvc):

```
#app/controllers/orders_controller.rb
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
   def new 
      @order = current_user.order.new
   end
   def create
      @order = current_user.order.new order_params
      if @order.save 
         @order.charge
      end
   end

   private

   def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:x, :y, :z, order_products_attributes: [:product, :qty])
   end
end
```

I'd have a more modular model structure:

```
#app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :order_products
   has_many :products, through: :order_products, extend ProductQty
   has_many :payments, inverse_of: :order

   scope :cart, -> { order_products }

   def total_price
      products.pluck(:price, :qty) #-> need to work out
   end

   def charge
       payment = payments.create
       payment.execute ? payment.success : payment.error #-> something conditional
   end
end

#app/models/order_product.rb
class OrderProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | order_id | product_id | qty | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :order
   belongs_to :product

end

#app/models/payment.rb
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :payments

   def execute
      Braintree::Transaction.sale(amount: order.total_price)
   end
end

#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :order_products
   has_many :orders, through: :order_products
end

#app/models/concerns/product_qty.rb
module ProductQty

    #Load
    def load
       products.each do |qty|
          proxy_association.target << qty
       end
    end

    #Private
    private

    #Products
    def products
       return_array = []
       through_collection.each_with_index do |through,i|
           associate = through.send(reflection_name)
           associate.assign_attributes({qty: items[i]})
           return_array.concat Array.new(1).fill( associate )
       end
       return_array
    end

    #######################
    #      Variables      #
    #######################

    #Association
    def reflection_name
            proxy_association.source_reflection.name
    end

    #Foreign Key
    def through_source_key
            proxy_association.reflection.source_reflection.foreign_key
    end

    #Primary Key
    def through_primary_key
            proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.active_record_primary_key
    end

    #Through Name
    def through_name
       proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.name
    end

    #Through
    def through_collection
       proxy_association.owner.send through_name
    end

    #Captions
    def items
       through_collection.map(&:qty)
    end

    #Target
    def target_collection
       proxy_association.target
    end

end
```

I wanted to include *cart* somewhere, I'll have to do that another time.

For now, you'd be able to do the following:

```
@order = current_user.orders.find params[:id]
@order.products.each do |product|
   product.qty #-> 5

@order.total_price #-> prices * qtys
```

--

This is not complete or tested, but I hope it shows you how you could improve your code structure dramatically, by making it modular. IE keep as many methods tied to your objects as possible.

In short, you should be able to do the following:

```
@order = current_users.orders.find params[:id]
if @order.payments.any?
   @payment = @order.payment.first
   @payment.success?
end
```

Comment: Thank you, that was great info

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `charge_user` method inside `OrdersController` class where you call this code:

```
transaction = OrderTransaction.new @order, params[:payment_method_nonce]
```

you don't really defined `@order` in this method, i.e. `@order` is `nil` here and that's causing the problem for you here and you are getting this error: `undefined method total_price for nil:NilClass`

Set `@order` value inside the `charge_user` method before you call this line of code and make sure `@order` is **NOT** `nil`:

```
transaction = OrderTransaction.new @order, params[:payment_method_nonce]
```

One possible solution is to modify your `charge_user` method to take an `order` argument like this:

```
def charge_user(order)
  transaction = OrderTransaction.new order, params[:payment_method_nonce]
  transaction.execute
  transaction.ok?
end
```

And, in your `create` method call like this:

```
if charge_user(@order_form.order)
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thank you for placing the order."
else
  # rest of the code
end
```

This will solve your issue.

Comment: I don't quite understand. The `order` is `nil`? But why does it work well when I just set the `create` method to just `redirect_to root_path`

Comment: As you get this error message: `undefined method total_price for nil:NilClass` when you call: `order.total_price` this indicates that it tries to call: `nil.total_price` as per your error message.

Comment: Oh wait, the problem is in your `charge_user` method where you call this code: `transaction = OrderTransaction.new @order, params[:payment_method_nonce]`, you don't really have `@order` here, its `nil` here, no? That's causing the issue here.

Comment: yeah, your right. Do I add `@order = Order.find params[:id]` to the charge_user method to find the order?

Comment: I tried adding `@order = Order.find params[:id] ` to charge_user and got `Couldn't find Order without an ID`. Not sure how to continue if the order is nil. This is after submitting user info and card info.

Comment: yeah, because your `params` does not have the `id` for this action. You have to somehow set the `@order` before you can call that code, otherwise `@order` will be `nil`. One way could be to change the `charge_user` method to take a `order` param so that you can send the order in the param from the `create` action like this: `charge_user(@order_form.order)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90663/discussion-between-jamesrocky-and-k-m-rakibul-islam).